# CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER does not set

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

Using curl to call API GET method with headers

but header not working

Response -- Failed to connect to 52.172.133.9: Permission denied

```
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_PORT => "25002",
            CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.eko.in:25002/ekoicici/v1/customers/mobile_number:8734818474?initiator_id=8734818474",
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 60,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => "CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1",
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                "cache-control: no-cache",
                "developer_key: $developerKey",
                "secret-key: $secret_key",
                "secret-key-timestamp: $secret_key_timestamp"
            )
        ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    var_dump($response);
    $err = curl_error($curl);
    var_dump($err);
    var_dump("developerKey--".$developerKey);
    var_dump("secret_key--".$secret_key);
    var_dump("secret_key_timestamp--".$secret_key_timestamp);
    curl_close($curl);
```

when hitting the request on this URL it requires key that's pass on the header but the header does not set on curl.
how to fix that's a problem...

Comment: What's in `$response`?

Comment: Error : "Failed to connect to 52.172.133.9: Permission denied".

Comment: Response: bool(false)